# how to solve problem? (about #chromedriver #WinError3 #path)

Tags: gpt-3

I created the following code for web scraping. However, I keep encountering the error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application'." How can I resolve this issue? Can you help me?
The methods I tried to resolve this issue are as follows:
Installed the latest version of ChromeDriver and Chrome.
Updated the Selenium library.
Utilized the ChromeDriver version management library (I manually reinstalled it after removing the library).
The result remains as follows.
[Result]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPFci.png)
And this is my original code.
[code]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa4c5.png)